# Comparing elements between a tuple and list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am comparing between a tuple of tuples and a list of tuples. 
I need to get the common elements out in a list.

Suppose that I have a tuple `k1= ((91, 25),(94, 27),(100, 22))`
    and a list `k2 = [(1,2), (4, 2), (100, 22)]`. How do I compare the elements in `k1` and `k2` 
    and get a list of the common elements?

Expected output for the above example:

```
[(100, 22)]
```

Comment: Are we to assume that the common element in your example is `(100,22)`?

Comment: @RedCricket  Hi! Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use set intersection:

```
set(k1).intersection(k2)
```

This returns:

```
{(100, 22)}
```

Comment: I upvoted, but the OP wants a list for output. You output a set. Maybe do `list(set(k1).intersection(k2))`

Comment: Won't it fail if the list has similar tuples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple list comprehension for that,

```
common_items = [item1 for item1 in list(k1) for item2 in k2 if item1 == item2]
```

Here's the output,

```
>>> common_items

[(100, 22)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i in k1 if i in k2]
```

you can use a simple list comprehension to iterate through each tuple in the lists and compare from there

Comment: oops i didnt know it works without too. i made the changes already

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
print([i for i in b if i not in (set(a)^set(b))])
```

`^` operator + `list comprehension` for getting the opposite values.

**Or Even better:**

```
print(set(a)&set(b))
```

**I recommend this, it's the shortest**

Comment: ... or just `set(k1) & set(k2)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Edited finished

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` Function

```
k1 = ((91, 25),(94, 27),(100, 22))
k2 = [(1,2), (4, 2), (100, 22)]
print filter(lambda x: x in k1,k2)
```

Result:

```
[(100, 22)]
```